# My practically brand new Macbook Pro 2020's screen elements are suddenly PINK

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, color, night-shift

I've tried powering off and on again. No love. Same with resetting PRAM.

It's even worse with Night Shift on. I need Night Shift on while working on detailed color projects at night, to save my poor old eyes. The pink windows and elements are unacceptable.

Anyone have any suggestions how to determine why my screen is pink?

Answer (score 2):

Without a screen image we won’t be able to diagnose if it’s LCD failure, cable failure, GPU failure or perhaps just a bad OS needing reinstall.

Even new machines can fail, so you can surely take advantage of the warranty service to have Apple help you as well if using this site for ideas isn’t quick enough.

Comment: Agreed, my **first** thought is return it for warranty, repair/replacement. Anything like this in the first 90 days (with no AppleCare) gets an automatic, "return it!" suggestion